# How to use ReflectionTestUtils.setField() to set a private String array?

Tags: java, junit5

I'm a little surprised here - in my class I have a `private String[] permissions;` field that I'd like to externally set while running a test. I thought of using `ReflectionTestUtils.setField()` but it doesn't look like there's a method to do that. Is there any other way I can go about doing this? And no, I'm not allowed to declare any setters for it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually possible to use `ReflectionTestUtils` here.

Assume that your class looks like:

```
public class Clazz {

    private String[] permissions;

    public String[] getPermissions() {
        return permissions;
    }
}
```

Then, in test you can do something like this:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

@Test
public void test() {
    Clazz clazz = new Clazz();

    String[] s = new String[2];
    s[0] = "asd";
    s[1] = "qwe";

    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(clazz, "permissions", s);

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[]{"asd", "qwe"}, clazz.getPermissions());
}
```

Relevant to `spring-boot-starter-test` 2.2.6.RELEASE (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/2.2.6.RELEASE).

```
<dependency>
    groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. Check the dependency and imports in the test class. Also, it would be great to see the text of your error.

Comment: My bad - I realised it's an issue with my IDE (IntelliJ) and not with the library